# Llamar funciones con otras funciones

Tags: javascript, funciones, function

Hola espero que esta pregunta no sea confusa pero ¿Como puedo llamar 2 funciones en una sola linea y que esta dependa de otra?
Ejemplo:

```
function().function();
```

Es algo asi como lo que hace JQuery.
Ejemplo:

```
$('h1').text('Hola mundo!');
```

Mi problema es que no tengo idea de como se haga eso y mi mayor intento para hacerlo fue el siguiente:

```
let auto = 0

function stTxt (color, backgroundColor) {
  document.onmouseup = function () {
    const element = document.createElement('span')
    element.setAttribute('id', `stElement${auto}`)
    window
      .getSelection()
      .getRangeAt(0)
      .surroundContents(element)
    const selectedElement = document.getElementById(`stElement${auto}`)
    selectedElement.style.color = color
    selectedElement.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    auto++

    function stSize (fontSize) {
      const elementSpan = document.getElementById(`stElement${auto}`)
      elementSpan.style.fontSize = fontSize
    }
  }
}
```

El problema de esto es que al poner así las funciones estas solo se llamarían de la siguiente forma de acuerdo a la documentación oficial de javascript:

```
function()();
```

La razón por la que quiero lograr hacer esto es que la segunda función quiero que sea solamente opcional para el usuario pero como se pueden dar cuenta esta función depende directamente de la anterior porque quisiera agregar mas funcionalidad a la función principal de ser requerido.

Comment: Lo siento, pero no entiendo que pretendes hacer. `function( ).method( )` es llamar a un método del objeto devuelto por una función, y `function( )( )` es llamar a una función devuelta por la llamada a otra. ¿ Cual es el problema con esto ?

Comment: Eso que muestras de  JQuery no solo es exclusivo de el y me parece se llama method chaining o encadenamiento de métodos

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias, se que varias librerias tenian esa funcion pero queria dar un ejemplo claro de lo que buscaba, investigare sobre el tema :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se puede hacer de muchas maneras, una de ellas es devolver un objeto:

```js
function funcion1() {

  const val = "valor de funcion 1";

  const funcion2 = () => {
    console.log(val+" valor de funcion dos");
  }
  const funcion3 = () => {
    console.log(val+" valor de funcion tres");
  }
  const funcion4 = () => {
    console.log(val+" valor de funcion cuatro");
  }

  return {
    funcion2: funcion2,
    funcion3: funcion3,
    funcion4: funcion4
  }

}

funcion1().funcion2();
funcion1().funcion3();
funcion1().funcion4();
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que buscaba y sirve para mi proposito :)